# fatal error checkdisalowAllocation in unity

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, unity-game-engine

i want to create AR app in unity, but in target image loading show this error, :fatal error `checkdisalowAllocation`. Allocating memory when it is not allowed to allocate memory . how can i fix it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 5.3.2 Unity3D version? It's incompatible with Vuforia.
Try to install a previous patched Unity3D version:

NOTICE: Unity 5.3.2 released on Jan. 28th is currently incompatible with Vuforia and may experience crashes when working in the Editor interface. In addition Unity 5.3.1p4 also shares the same incompatibility.

Unity 5.3.1f1 feature release or Unity 5.3.1p3 patch release are recommended to use for now.

A bug report for this issue has been filed with Unity.

Edit:

Download patched versions:
https://unity3d.com/es/unity/qa/patch-releases

Vuforia forum:
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/unity-error-checkdisalowallocation